# c++ exception with backstrace not printing the caller function details

Tags: c++, exception, callstack

I have some exception code like below

```
class BaseException : public std::exception {
    public:
        BaseException(string  str) : error_string(str){
            printStackTrace();
        }
        BaseException() = default;
        virtual ~BaseException() throw() = default;
        virtual const char *what() const throw(){return error_string.c_str();}
        void printStackTrace() {
            void *array[10];
            size_t size;
            size = backtrace(array, 10);
            backtrace_symbols_fd(array, size, STDERR_FILENO);
        }
        string error_string;
};    
void baz() {
    throw BaseException("tetsingException");
} 

void bar() { baz(); }
void foo() { bar(); }  

int main() {

    try{
        foo();
    }
    catch(BaseException &e){
        cout << e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I run this, I get below output

```
/home/user/sample/Debug/Exceptionwithstrace[0x4010c3]
/home/user/sample/Debug/Exceptionwithstrace[0x40104f]
/home/user/sample/Debug/Exceptionwithstrace[0x400eb5]
/home/user/sample/Debug/Exceptionwithstrace[0x400f1b]
/home/user/sample/Debug/Exceptionwithstrace[0x400f26]
/home/user/sample/Debug/Exceptionwithstrace[0x400f36]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fda68538f45]
/home/user/sample/Debug/Exceptionwithstrace[0x400da9]
tetsingException
```

function names are not printed, I need to get printing of function name also, like below , how to get something like below

```
/home/user/sample/Debug/Exceptionwithstrace[BaseException]
/home/user/sample/Debug/Exceptionwithstrace[baz]
/home/user/sample/Debug/Exceptionwithstrace[bar]
/home/user/sample/Debug/Exceptionwithstrace[foo]
/home/user/sample/Debug/Exceptionwithstrace[main]
```

Comment: i think you are required to have extra flags like `-rdynamic` on linux with gcc

Comment: already I added, my current flags are  g++ --std=c++11 -g -rdynamic -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"

Comment: Have you tried without -g3 and also with -gdwarf?

Comment: Does it not show the mangled function names? Something along the lines of `/home/user/sample/Debug/Exceptionwithstrace(_Z3foov+0x9)[0x4010c3]`

Comment: Hi, yes its printing now, but its not pretty , I want just function name, its printing full symbol .. also its possible to print the line number ?

Comment: I don't know if backtrace supports that, but you can demangle the function names when using gcc: [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html). Just need's a lot of work...